# javascript type writer with multiline and html tags

Tags: javascript, html

I need a javascript effect to simulate a typewriter on a website

I have found a great codepen: 
https://codepen.io/stevn/pen/jEZvXa

The problem is that I'm not able to output any html tags
(like phisically print the < and > symbol)

Example output

```
<html>
<body>
<p>test</p>
```

I tried to set the option "writingTag" to true but wont work.

EDIT: 
I tried with & lt; e & gt; but nothing

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to enclose your html with pre tag with 'typewriter' id attribute, as in example?

try to remove this lines of code

```
if (HTML[cursorPosition] === "<") {
            tempTypeSpeed = 0;
            if (tagOpen) {
                tagOpen = false;
                writingTag = true;
            } else {
                tag = "";
                tagOpen = true;
                writingTag = true;
                tag += HTML[cursorPosition];
            }
        }
```

Comment: It seems that it only recognizes text, you need to somehow escape or decode the html tags

Answer (score 0):

It's slightly tricky, but could work.
Instead add correct `&lt;` and `&gt;` you could use visual similar, but  **not** so special character, for example try `&#65308;Foo&#65310;`